# Ajax pass values from view to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

so I'm trying to pass some values from my view to the controller, the controller gets a list and returns it.

when I try to get the values from my textboxes etc. they are all undefined... not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here. pretty new to javascript..

here's the js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getFreeApartements").on('click', function () {

        var amounta = $('#amounta').val();
        var amountc = $('#amountc').val();
        var amountan = $('#animals').val();
        var arr = $('#arrival').val();
        var dep = $('#departure').val();
        var atype = $('#atype').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: { 'amountp': amounta, 'amountc': amountc, 'amountanimals': amountan, 'arrival': arr, 'departure': dep, 'apartmentType': atype },
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFreeApartements", "Bookings")',
            success: function (result) {
                $('freeAp').html(result);
            }
        });
        alert(amounta); // --> return undefined

    });
});
```

textboxinput field

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adult, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10" id="amountp" name="amountp">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adult, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adult, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
        public ActionResult GetFreeApartements(int ap, int ac, int aa, DateTime arr, DateTime dep, ApartmentType type)
    {
 //do some stuff with received values here...
        var freeApartements = db.Apartments.ToList();
        return Json(freeApartements, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I also tried serializeArray without any success... 
I'm not getting any errors in the explorer console..
the function gets called, but values are null.. --> undefined should be the error.

any ideas?

Comment: first idea, you post `amountp` but in your controller method you call it `ap` (same goes for the others ones). They should match name if I recall correctly

Comment: You're passing `amountp`, `amountc`, etc as the names in the `data` json, but there's no parameter named `amountp` or `amountc` in your controller. Try to make them match, i.e change the json to `data: { ap: amounta,`

Comment: all right did so. but still no success.

Comment: you say your the function gets called. what does the request look like?

Comment: you're talking about the request in the controller? if so.. I have a db statement which returns the free apartments with some extra parameters I'm passing from the view. but as long as I'm not receiving anything from the view I think this doesnt really matter at this point?!

Comment: no, but you say the method in the controller gets hit, so you should be able  to set a breakpoint and check what is in the httpContext ... what is the actual URL that `$.ajax` calls. You should be able to check that on the server side-

Comment: The only control you have show is `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adult, ...)` which generates an input with `id="Adult"`. Show the view where you generate inputs with `id="amounta"` etc. And the methods parameter names must match the names of your javascript object properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer might help you

In the EditorFor (Text box) assign the id attribute. Assess the text box element using id in Ajax.

example

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adult, new { htmlAttributes = new { id="adultTextBox" @class = "form-control" } })
```

In the above example I have assigned the `id="adultTextBox"` assess it in ajax like `$("#adultTextBox").val()`

Answer (score 0):

So right now you have an issue with how asynchronous calls work. Your `$.ajax` line is going to get executed, and then right after that, the `alert` line will be executed - it doesn't wait for your asynchronous call to resolve before running the `alert` (that's the point of asynchronous calls). What you should be doing, is checking the value of `amounta` inside the `success` callback.

I modified the below to only include the relevant parts to illustrate the point. I also added the line to refetch the value of the `amounta` DOM element after setting the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getFreeApartements").on('click', function () {

        var amounta = $('#amounta').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: { ... data },
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFreeApartements", "Bookings")',
            success: function (result) {
                $('freeAp').html(result);
                amounta = $('#amounta').val();
                alert(amounta);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

You may have other issues with your controller ... but the above sample should fix your JavaScript woes you'd be seeing.

Comment: yes you're right! but still my value is undefined. so the error should be somewhere in the script? or is there anything wrong with the input form?

Comment: I've never used ASP.NET but I imagine something is not as you expect in the return value of your AJAX call. Try to investigate what `result` is and see if that leads you down any roads. From the way your code is structured, it seems like it would be JSON, which would make your `$('freeAp').html(result);` not do what you expect most likely.

Answer (score 0):

in your textboxinput code. Try using the id of the editorFor. Eg `#Adult`
Instead of the wrapper `#amountp` 
As the id In your JavaScript